# tabs with javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Well I’m having a hard time figuring this out, the deal it’s that I’m using this code in some tabs that I have, it works perfect in all browser except for Internet Explorer 10, 9, the tabs are showing but when you click on them the information doesn’t change. So after looking what the error it’s I have found that in IE one if it’s not running, here’s the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
    initialize: function(selector) {
        var self = this;
        $$(selector+' a').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
    },

    initTab: function(el) {
        el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
        if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
            this.showContent(el);
        }
        el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
    },
    showContent: function(a) {
        var li = $(a.parentNode), ul = $(li.parentNode);
        ul.select('li', 'ol').each(function(el){
            var contents = $(el.id+'_contents');
            //the problem lies here, in IE the if doesn't run
            if (el == li) {
                el.addClassName('active');
                contents.show();
            } else {
               el.removeClassName('active');
               contents.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
new Varien.Tabs('.product-tabs');    
</script>
```

So the deal it’s that the condition of the IF statement it’s not running and I have no clue of why.

I'm using  IE 10 and 9 since IE 8 it's working fine, also I'm not getting any errors in the console of IE .

Comment: Try using .addClass() and .removeClass() instead of .addClassName() and .removeClassName().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have figured out what happen

```
ul.select('li', 'ol').each(function(el){
```

so in this line i had 'li' and 'ol', since the page didn't have any 'ol' the page in IE wasn0t working so since I remove

Answer (score 0):

Open the F12 tools and use the debugger. Set a break point on the line. See what li and el are and see if they are actually equal. I would probably try to compare the id or some other value that is unique to the li you are trying to match. you have to remember you are comparing two instances of jQuery the way your are doing it right now. To actually compare the node (element) you would do it this way: li[0] === el[0];

Try the debugger and use the watch window to see what the values actually are and try to compare the actual node, not jQuery instances.

Answer (score 0):

If Your code is working fine with IE8 then try following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

This will make your code IE 8 compatible no matter which version of IE you are using. 
The only thing you should take care is, your code should work fine in IE 8.